# Control Fujitsu Softune debugger

Tags: debugging, embedded, softune

Is there a way to control the Fujitsu Softune debugger with an other application(e.g. Eclipse)? I think about sending the command mentioned in the documentation of Softune and parse the output, but also other approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There is pluging for eclipse; file name is "FujitsuF2MC16_1.0.1.jar", look for it on this page:

http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/70413

Complile en debug in eclipse.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by controlling the Fujitsu Softune debugger?

If what you want to do is to start a debugging session with your freshly-compiled .abs file, you can do the following.

In the Eclipse environment add a button or shortcut to call the make utility to make a `debug:`. Your makefile would have an entry like:

```
debug: $(make_vars)
# start debugger
make -f$(make_vars) -f$(make_dir)/$(cfg) cfg="$(cfg)"   debug_session
```

In the make entry for `debug_session` you put something like:

```
echo UPDATING SOFTUNE-3 PROJECT FOR  DEBUGGING;\
$(subst \,/,$(DIR_SOFTUNE_WORKBENCH))/bin/Fs907s.exe softune/E7x_proj.wsp    2>/dev/null;
```

I hope this was useful.